# Retrieving PDF signature names and dates with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I need to read from a number of pdf files (digitally signed) the follwing info:

- date of creation
- signers name(s) and date of signature(s)
  Can you suggest me a VBA routine doing so?

I've tried this code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim formUI As Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc
    Dim srcDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc, formDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim jso As Object
    Dim strFullPath As String, text1 As String, text2 As String

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set formUI = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    Set srcDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    strFullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    srcDoc.Open (strFullPath)

    If formUI.Open(strFullPath, "") = True Then
        Set formDoc = formUI.GetPDDoc()
        Set jso = formDoc.GetJSObject()

        ' EXTRACT FORM FIELDS' TEXT
         text1 = jso.GetField("MFR_ctrl33605579").Value
    End If

   ' UNINTIALIZING PDF OBJECTS
    Set jso = Nothing
    Set formDoc = Nothing
    Set srcDoc = Nothing
    Set formUI = Nothing
    Set AcroApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

However right on the first line it returns "user defined type not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you haven't enabled the Acrobot library.

Assuming you have the library available...

1. Within the Excel workbook that you're using to perform the VBA, go to the vba editor page.
2. Click on TOOLS → References (see below)
3. You'll get a screen that lists a few items checked, scroll down and look for Acrobat, then check it and hit okay.

The `Compile Error:User-defined type not defined` will no longer get thrown when you run the routine.

[image]

[image]